# Add Notification Customer Registration About Shipping Restriction in Magento 2

Tags: php, magento2, magento-2.3

I want to add a notification that appears on the registration page - only when California is selected as a state. Otherwise it will not display. I am unsure of the parameters and am getting an error. I am using Magento 2.3.

The current code on the registration.phtml is the following:

```
<label for="region_id" class="label">
  <span>
    <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()>getFrontendLabel('region') ?>
  </span>
</label>
<div class="control">
  <select id="region_id" name="region_id" title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('region') ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
    <option value=""><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Please select a region, state or province.')) ?></option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" id="region" name="region" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getRegion()) ?>" title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('region') ?>" class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region')) ?>" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

and my PHP is the following:

```
<?php if ($Region == 12) {echo '<div class="no-cali">We do not ship to California.</div>';} else { echo '';} ?>
```

Comment: Please include some more information, such as the steps you have taken to debug this issue or research you have already done, so we can better answer your question.

Comment: I have tried updating my PHP included above with the following variables: region_id, code, default_name and name. None of them have worked.